# Using simpleplot (codeskulptor) in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, codeskulptor

I already used the following import to use simpleGUI in python 2.7 from my desktop.

```
try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
```

Now, I want to plot numerical values in the frame. Is there anyway to do that. I have issue with simpleplot.

This is my whole code:

```
     # Import the module
try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
    import simpleplot

# Define event handler functions
def input_handler(x):
    pass
def button_handler():
    dataset1 = {3: 5, 8: 2, 1: 3}
    dataset2 = [(1, 2), (4, 7), (2, 5), (7, 6)]
    simpleplot.plot_lines('Sample', 400, 300, 'x', 'y', [dataset1,     dataset2],   True, ['dataset1', 'dataset2'])
    pass

# Create a frame
f = simplegui.create_frame("UWB GUI",CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
# Register event handlers
textField1=f.add_input("File Name", input_handler,100)

f.add_button("Filter", button_handler,100)

# Start frame and timers
f.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do these imports:

```
try:
    import simplegui
    import simpleplot
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleplot as simpleplot
```

You can see more informations on the documentation of SimpleGUICS2Pygame:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tips.html

The idea is to try to import simplegui and simpleplot. If the program runs in CodeSkulptor, then it's fine.
If the program runs with standard Python, then these first imports failed and then imports SimpleGUICS2Pygame version renamed.

P.-S.: two variables CANVAS_WIDTH and CANVAS_HEIGHT in your code are not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working now. However, when I plot using the simpleplot, it opens a new window. Is it possible to plot in the same frame?

Comment: No, it is not possible. It is the same behavior in CodeSkulptor:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_Blrcg2Wn8KHsRqO.py

Comment: Is there any GUI package, so I can plot in the frame?